# Go lang template: for construction

Tags: templates, go

Golang http/template has substitution features, `if` construction, but I didn't find `for` construction. How can I iterate through a slice? Like this:

```
{{for x in xs}}
  Hello, {{x.Name}}!
{{end}}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

use `range`

```
{{range xs}}
  Hello, {{.Name}}!
{{end}}
```

Comment: Where did you find it in reference?

Comment: Oh my all that constructions covered in documentation for text/template. Thank you!